# Coping images (bitmaps) massively in vb.net by clicking a button

Tags: vb.net, image, copying

I create a project and one of its features is to copy images (or bitmaps) by clicking a button. What I mean is that by clicking once only one small picture will be shown, by clicking an other one time two small pictures will be shown, by clicking 3 times there would be 8 etc. (2^(the times the button is clicked)). Can you help me with the code because I can't express it in vb.net code.

I thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have troubles to understand your question, could you clarify in what way you want the pictures to be shown? And if u want to copy them or just show these pictures in some sort of preview Form?

(sorry to post this As an Answer, but im missing reputation to comment your innitial question)

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your response. These images I'm talking about are smaill dont that will represent cells (the known cells of biology but thats not the point). These images should be shown in a canvas and being copied as the cells are duplicated. So, the point of the project is to show the rate of duplication of some kinda of cells. I hope I helped you understand what I asked. PS. What you mean that the images can be shown in some sort of preview Form?

Comment: @AlexandrosMylonas i'm wondering where you want to display the images, inside your main form? inside a second form? or do you have something else in mind? maybe you can illustrate what you mean and upload it?

Comment: That's approximately what I have in my mind http://prnt.sc/etzobf It would be better if the images where near from each other